# A continuous choice of invertible elements

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $A$ be  a  simple unital $C^{*}$ algebra with invertible elements $G(A)$. Assume that $A^{*}$ is its dual space, which is equipped with the weak star topology.

> Is there a continuous map $\alpha:A^{*}-\{0\}\to G(A)$ with $\alpha(\phi)\in \ker \phi$, in the other words: $\phi(\alpha_{\phi})=0$  where $\alpha_{\phi}=\alpha(\phi)$?
>
> If the answer is yes, is there an extension of $\phi$ to whole $A^{*}$?

Note that there is a (possible) non continuous $\phi$ as above.(As  a  consequence of the [Gleason Kahane Zelazko theorem](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gleason-Kahane-%C5%BBelazko_theorem))

What  about if  we  consider the norm topology for the dual space?

Comment: Hmm... I guess you’re imposing the simplicity condition on $ A $ so as to rule out the existence of non-trivial characters on $ A $ that would make the assertion false?

Comment: @Transcendental  exactly for this reason that you said.

Comment: You would also have to exclude the case $ A = \mathbb{C} $, which is unital and simple. The non-zero continuous linear functionals on $ \mathbb{C} $ are precisely those defined by $ \phi_{\lambda}: z \mapsto \lambda z $ for $ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}^{\times} $. As
$$
  G(\mathbb{C}) \cap \ker(\phi_{\lambda})
= \mathbb{C}^{\times} \cap \{ 0_{\mathbb{C}} \}
= \varnothing
$$
for each $ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}^{\times} $, the answer to your question is negative in this special case.